# If $\mathrm{P}(1)+\ldots +\mathrm{P}(n)=n^5 $ then$ \int_0^1\,\mathrm{P}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = ?$

Tags: integration, polynomials

Given the polynomial function $\mathrm P$ defined on $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and knowing that $\mathrm{P}(1) + \cdots + \mathrm{P}(n)=n^5$ where $ n>0$ find $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \mathrm P(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$. I'm trying to understand what this means but can't figure it out. How could I possibly find
$\mathrm{P}(x)$ ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(x)$ must be a fourth degree polynomial $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4$.

If you solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}p(1)=1\\p(1)+p(2)=2^5\\p(1)+p(2)+p(3)=3^5\\p(1)+p(2)+p(3)+p(4)=4^5\\p(1)+p(2)+p(3)+p(4)+p(5)=5^5\text,\end{array}\right.$$you will get $a=1$, $b=-5$, $c=10$, $d=-10$, and $e=5$. So$$\int_0^1P(x)\,dx=\int_0^11-5x+10x^2-10x^3+5x^4\,dx=\frac13.$$

Comment: How is it possible?! Why are mine and yours answer different? Can you please recheck your calculations?

Comment: Oh!! Those are the same, your one is expanded form of $n^5-(n-1)^5$

Comment: @JaideepKhare Right! And your solution is better than mine, of course.

Answer (score 13):

Hint :

$$\underbrace{P(1)+\ldots P(n-1)}_{=(n-1)^5}+P(n)=n^5$$